# Cannot recognize an old external usb harddrive

Tags: mount, hard-disk, corruption

I want to check the content of an old external harddrive and probably delete it all (and maybe overwrite it) before throwing it away. Maybe it's not even worth checking the content and just straight up delete it.

But I can't get it to be mounted. In fact, it's not even being properly recognized. Using `fdisk -l` doesn't show the disk. Using `dmesg` results in this:

```
[21245.965254] usb 3-11: USB disconnect, device number 91
[21246.264607] usb 3-11: new high-speed USB device number 92 using xhci_hcd
[21246.409937] usb 3-11: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0420, bcdDevice= 5.10
[21246.409946] usb 3-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[21246.409950] usb 3-11: Product: Portable Drive
[21246.409952] usb 3-11: Manufacturer: Verbatim
[21246.409954] usb 3-11: SerialNumber: 1812081600007415
[21246.411271] usb-storage 3-11:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[21246.411526] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-11:1.0
```

Using `lsusb` shows this:

```
Bus 003 Device 093: ID 18a5:0420 Verbatim, Ltd Portable Drive
```

What do I do?

Comment: Anything in `/dev` ?

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan I don't see any new /dev/sdX device

Comment: Maybe just get a hammer and slash it into peaces. Probably faster than having to ask here about it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9wsjroVlu8

Comment: @john-jones fair